# Debugging an exe that's run by another exe

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, exe

I took over a project recently, and I'm not sure how the last guy was debugging this... I have two executables, one eventually runs another. I will call them **exe1** and **exe2**. These were created in C# and I use Visual Studio 2015

Running **exe1** works fine. It does some stuff, and eventually kicks off **exe2**. **exe2** eventually errors out. It's writing to my log file:

> BaseException:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set
>   to an instance of an object.

(I can usually troubleshoot that error. I'm sure it's just an issue creating an object or something, but my trial and errors method of fixing it have not worked so far. )

I don't have the source code for **exe1** so I can't rig up some super program to do everything in one go (which would allow me to debug). Is there a way I can set breakpoints and step through **exe2** doing its thing?

I should add, **exe2** NEEDS **exe1** to run. **exe1** does a bunch of stuff, and without it **exe2** just crashes immediately.

Comment: Can you attach a debugger when exe2 launches?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to debug a compiled executable in Visual Studio.  What you could do however is use one of the many tools (I use JustDecompile from Telerik) to see what the source code in exe2 is.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I'm not familiar with that process. Is that a function of Visual Studio?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio allows to [debug child processes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/11/24/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool/) for some years now. I have tried it having the code for both projects (parent and child processes) and it works pretty well. Not sure if it could work in your case having only the code for the exe2 program, but I think it's worth the try. Set the exe1 as the debug target for the project, having the child debugging activated, and see if it hits breakpoints in exe2...

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the code for **exe2**, you can add a [`Debugger.Launch()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Diagnostics_Debugger_Launch) to the code and that will stop the program and allow you to attach a debugger at that line of code.

You can add this as the first line of the `main` method to ensure you catch it right at startup.

Comment: This is an interesting tool. I added that Debugger.Launch(). How do you actually step through the code? When VS pops up it says "The application is in break mode. Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code)."

Comment: Make sure you are running debug code (not release) and when you open visual studio, it should take you to the line of code that has the debugger.launch.  If you are running multiple threads, you can use the Visual Studio thread window to switch between them.

Comment: Also, depending on your debugging settings (Just My Code, Debug .Net Framework Code, ..) you may be deeper down in the framework code. You can use the Stack Trace window to navigate back up to your code.

Comment: How would debug mode work? I build the release version to create exe2. I don't see any option to change to debug mode once the debugger pops up. I am able to click continue to the point where I get to the error I was having, so that's a good sign, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways may solve this.

**1**. Using `Debugger.Launch()` as John gave the answer above.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Debugger.Launch();

                //Rest of your code 
            }
```

This will allow you to attach to your running visual studio or start a new instance.

**2.** When the previous one does not work, another way is to put a loop at the start of the code to check if a debugger is attached, this gives you enough time to do the "Attach to process" method.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(!Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); //Sleep 1 seconds and check again.
    }

    //Rest of your code  
}
```